# How to set TLS option in gRPC client of flutter?

Tags: flutter, security, ssl, grpc, pem

Thanks for watching this problem. I use grpc as backend in GCloud and flutter in front end, but fail to communicate. As I want to set tls connection, but if fails to read the .pem file. Here is my client init code

```
    final trustedRoot = new File('cert.pem').readAsBytesSync();
    final channelCredentials =
        new ChannelCredentials.secure(certificates: trustedRoot);
    final channel = ClientChannel(
      '101.164.19.23',
      port: 8080,
      options: ChannelOptions(
        credentials: channelCredentials,
      ),
    );

    return testClient(channel);
```

and it reports error:

```
Error: Unsupported operation: _Namespace
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:61406/dart_sdk.js:5333:11)
    at Function.get _namespace [as _namespace] (http://localhost:61406/dart_sdk.js:55298:17)
    at io._File.new.openSync (http://localhost:61406/dart_sdk.js:53257:45)
    at io._File.new.readAsBytesSync (http://localhost:61406/dart_sdk.js:53320:25)
    at web_stub.WebStub.new.getGrpcStub (http://localhost:61406/packages/piaodi/client/base_stub.dart.lib.js:46:52)
    at new grpc_client_singleton.GrpcClientSingleton._internal (http://localhost:61406/packages/piaodi/client/grpc_client_singleton.dart.lib.js:42:28)
    at get _singleton (http://localhost:61406/packages/piaodi/client/grpc_client_singleton.dart.lib.js:53:14)
    at Function.desc.get [as _singleton] (http://localhost:61406/dart_sdk.js:5869:17)
    at Function.new (http://localhost:61406/packages/piaodi/client/grpc_client_singleton.dart.lib.js:36:56)
    at lottery_page._LotteryPageState.new._joinLottery (http://localhost:61406/packages/piaodi/ui/lottery_page.dart.lib.js:464:71)
    at _joinLottery.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:61406/dart_sdk.js:39051:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:61406/dart_sdk.js:39082:7)
    at lottery_page._LotteryPageState.new.[_joinLottery] (http://localhost:61406/packages/piaodi/ui/lottery_page.dart.lib.js:462:20)
    at lottery_page._LotteryPageState.new.<anonymous> (http://localhost:61406/packages/piaodi/ui/lottery_page.dart.lib.js:454:72)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:61406/dart_sdk.js:39051:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:61406/dart_sdk.js:39082:7)
    at http://localhost:61406/packages/piaodi/ui/lottery_page.dart.lib.js:453:1088
    at ink_well._InkResponseState.new.[_handleTap] (http://localhost:61406/packages/flutter/src/material/icon_button.dart.lib.js:50511:42)
```

I have searched the google and stack overflow, but find no useful information to solve this. If you have experience in this kind of problem, please help me or give me some information. Thanks a lot.